# Multithreaded bubblesort using a threshold

Tags: java, arrays, multithreading, merge

So I got this assignment where I had to split an array into two, split those split arrays in 2, etc... up to a certain threshold.

So if my threshold was lets say 1000 it would be like:
10k>2x 5k>4x 2500>8x 1250>16x 625 (numbers in array).

Then I'd have to sort those arrays and merge them:
16x 625 (merged)>8x 1250 (merged)>4x 2500 (merged)>2x 5000 (merged)>1x 10k. 
All of them must remain sorted.

So I think I got pretty far but it seems like it does not work the way I want it to. I tried multiple things to figure what is going wrong but I haven#t figured it out which is why I am here.

Can someone help me understand what I am doing wrong and give me a solution?

**Bubblesort.java:**

```
package PartThree;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Bubblesort implements Runnable {
public List<Integer> arrayList;
private int threshold;
private int middle;

public Bubblesort(List<Integer> arrayList, int threshold) {
    this.arrayList = arrayList;
    this.threshold = threshold;
    this.middle = arrayList.size() / 2;
    System.out.println(arrayList.size() + " ha");
}

@Override
public void run() {
    if (arrayList.size() <= treshold) {
        sort();
    }else if(threshold<arrayList.size()){
        Bubblesort rLeft = new Bubblesort(arrayList.subList(0, middle), threshold);
        Bubblesort rRight = new Bubblesort(arrayList.subList(middle, arrayList.size()), threshold);


        Thread tLeft = new Thread(rLeft);
        Thread tRight = new Thread((rRight));
        tRight.start();
        tLeft.start();
        try {
            tLeft.join();
            tRight.join();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        merge(rLeft.arrayList, rRight.arrayList);
        System.out.println(arrayList.size() + ":size");
    }
}

private void merge(List<Integer> left, List<Integer> right) {
    int i = 0, j = 0, k = 0;
    List<Integer> temp = new ArrayList<>();
    while (i < left.size() && j < right.size()) {
        if (left.get(i) < right.get(j)) {
            temp.add(k, left.get(i));
            i++;
        } else {
            temp.add(k, right.get(j));
            j++;
        }
        k++;
    }
    while (i < left.size()) {
        temp.add(k, left.get(i));
        i++;
        k++;
    }
    while (j < right.size()) {
        temp.add(k, right.get(j));
        j++;
        k++;
    }
    arrayList = temp;
    temp.clear();
}

private void sort() {
    int i, j, tijdelijk;
    for (j = 0; j < arrayList.size(); j++) {
        for (i = 1; i < arrayList.size() - j; i++) {
            if (arrayList.get(i - 1) > arrayList.get(i)) {
                tijdelijk = arrayList.get(i);
                arrayList.set(i, arrayList.get(i - 1));
                arrayList.set(i - 1, tijdelijk);
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

**Implementation:**

```
package PartThree;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;

public class API {
private Random random = new Random();
private List<Integer> array_unsorted_main = new ArrayList<>();
private int maxSize;

private Thread t1;

private void run(){
    this.maxSize = 10000;

    for (int i = 0; i < maxSize; i++) {
        array_unsorted_main.add(random.nextInt(10000));
    }
    t1 = new Thread(new Bubblesort(array_unsorted_main,1000));
    t1.start();
    try {
        t1.join();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

    public static void main(String args[]){
        new PartThree.API().run();
    }
}
```

Please help me out, thank you for your time.

Comment: What makes you think it doesn't work the way you want and what things have you tried exactly?

Comment: Wewll for once, it doesnt merge and I tried to add several checks for "mergeReady".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of your problems is in your `merge` method you do `arrayList = temp;` and then do `temp.clear()` thereby clearing `arrayList` since it now points to `temp`.

Remove the `temp.clear()` statement so `arrayList` will retain the sorted values.

Comment: if i dont i get a concurrentmodificationexception